# Can't find private key from certificate

Tags: java, security, applet, digital-certificate

We are working on encryption-decryption using applet. We find some unexpected issue with digital certificate. One system has certificate and we can't find the private key from that certificate but by installing the same certificate again works fine.

```
Java Plug-in 10.25.2.17
Using JRE version 1.7.0_25-b17 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
User home directory = C:\Users\admin
```

To access private key we are using below code.

```
private PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(String pubkey, KeyStore browser) {
        PrivateKey privateKey = null;
        String pubKey1 = "";
        if (browser != null) {
            try {
                Field spiField = KeyStore.class.getDeclaredField("keyStoreSpi");
                spiField.setAccessible(true);
                KeyStoreSpi spi = (KeyStoreSpi) spiField.get(browser);
                Field entriesField = spi.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("entries");
                entriesField.setAccessible(true);
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                Collection entries = (Collection) entriesField.get(spi);
                for (Object entry : entries) {
                    String alias = (String) invokeGetter(entry, "getAlias");
                    X509Certificate[] certificateChain = (X509Certificate[]) invokeGetter(entry, "getCertificateChain");
                    for (X509Certificate current : certificateChain) {
                        pubKey1 = this.bASE64Encoder.encode(current.getPublicKey().getEncoded());
                        if (pubkey.equals(pubKey1) && !pubkey.equals("")) {
                            privateKey = (PrivateKey) invokeGetter(entry, "getPrivateKey");
                            return privateKey;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        return privateKey;
    }
```

Comment: You don't need all this reflection to call the KeyStore API. Try using what's published.

Comment: can't get it.. Will you plz explain it with bit more details. Like which line of code I have to change...

Comment: Change them *all.* Throw it all away and have a look the Javadoc. There are already public methods in KeyStore to enumerate the contents and to find what type each element is.

Comment: Element type means?  Are you talking about hierarchy of certificate..That I can get like if `digitalSignature (1)` than Sign certificate like wise for other KEY IDENTIFICATION..but here the problem I don't have a specific case when same certificate private key become null. Now In browser I have three certificate which has private key null. I removed one of them, and added it again then I get expected private key. Now I want to check remaining 2 certificate. what is actually issue of `private key null`? `how private key become null for same certificate?`I want root cause.

Comment: By 'element type' I mean certificate or key. I suggest you calm down and read the public API as I have already suggested. There are methods to retrieve certificates, keys, and Iterators. You won't get anywhere on your present course.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find private key in certificate because it must be in your keystore, of course, if you generated your cert with its [CSR](http://www.sslshopper.com/what-is-a-csr-certificate-signing-request.html) :)

As a tip, I may ask is the cert expired for example?

Anyway, the question is pretty unclear :( If you have cert you must have the keystore which was used to sign your app... It would be better you give more details...